# Cart page shipping method loading issue. Magento2

Tags: magento2, cart, shipping-methods

I have set 'Minimum Order Amount' to 25 for Free Shipping & other shipping method is 'Flat rate'. My issue is when I redirect back from paypal to cart page after canceling the payment from paypal the cart page shows Flat rate Shipping method first while loading later when the loading of page is over it displays correct Shipping method i.e. 'Free Shipping'

In short, the loading under 'Estimate Shipping & Tax' displays incorrect shipping method while the loading spinner is on.

[image]